# Секунды в формат времени

Tags: python-3.x, время

помогите пожалуйста создать функцию, которая будет обрабатывать секунды

На выводе нужно получить - не возвращать 0 месяцев 0 дней 0 часов и тд если они по нулям

Допустим передали 60 секунд - возвращал текст (1 минута, 20 сек) допустим
Допустим передали 3600 секунд - возвращал (1 час 1 минута 20 сек) допустим

Сейчас есть такая функция но как правильно модифицировать я не знаю(

```
def seconds_to_str(seconds):
    mm, ss = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    if hh == 0 and mm == 0:
        return "%02d сек" % (ss)
    elif hh == 0:
        return "%02d мин, %02d сек" % (mm, ss)
    else:
        return "%02d час, %02d мин, %02d сек" % (hh, mm, ss)
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. 60 секунд - это ровно 1 минута, а вовсе не 1 минута 20 секунд. 3600 секунд - это ровно один час, и никакой минуты и двадцати секунд там нет.

Comment: Зачем ее модицифровать? Что не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте динамически склеивать результирющую строку:

```
def seconds_to_str(seconds):
    mm, ss = divmod(seconds, 60)
    hh, mm = divmod(mm, 60)
    ret = f"{hh:02d} час" if hh else ""
    ret += ", " if ret else ""
    ret += f"{mm:02d} мин" if mm else ""
    ret += ", " if ret else ""
    ret += f"{ss:02d} сек"
    return ret
```

Примеры:

```
In [42]: seconds_to_str(59)
Out[42]: '59 сек'

In [43]: seconds_to_str(159)
Out[43]: '02 мин, 39 сек'

In [44]: seconds_to_str(3666)
Out[44]: '01 час, 01 мин, 06 сек'
```